# XMLHttpRequest.response really null or not

Tags: javascript, ajax

Making AJAX call to a non-existent database element. Then the handler looks like this:

```
if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200 && xhr.response !== null) {
    console.log('response type is ' + typeof xhr.response); // string
    console.log('response is ' + xhr.response);             // null
    // rest of the handler//
{
```

The question is, why my handler is executing the block (it always goes to console and log string and null), if i stated to do it only if response is not null ?

Comment: Well, if it's really saying `response type is string` and `response is null`, then clearly the response is the string `"null"`.

Comment: Rather than stumbling around in the dark with a `console.log` torch, though, I suggest turning on the lights using the powerful debugger built into your browser. Set a breakpoint within that block and inspect the value of `xhr.response` while the code is paused on the breakpoint.

Comment: Also look at the Network tab of the developer tools and examine the raw data of the HTTP response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if it's really logging

```
response type is string
response is null
```

...then clearly the response is the **string** `"null"`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback, including the above comments. It makes my JS initiation easier. Would vote for the answer, having the enough reputation.